# How to check core dump enabledness status in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, core, ulimit, segmentation-fault

```
$ ulimit
unlimited
$ sleep 2 && killall -SEGV cat &
[1] 11358
$ cat
Segmentation fault
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ ulimit
unlimited
$ sleep 2 && killall -SEGV cat &
[1] 11462
$ cat
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

1. How to check the current status in bash for `-c`?
2. Why it prints `unlimited` both times, but different limitations apply? What does this `unlimited` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `ulimit -c` or `ulimit -a`.
2. `ulimit` seems to be equivalent to `ulimit -f` (show limit for max file size), not to `ulimit -a` as I initially thought.